# Unable to create new Pipeline in Azure DevOps: "The directory object quota limit for the Principal has been exceeded"

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a new pipeline in Azure DevOps. In the configure tab I choose Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service and select the appropriate values such as Cluster name, namespace, and etc..

When I click next, azure Devops tries to validate and create the pipeline but then it displays the following error :

[image: Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: The directory object quota limit for the Principal has been exceeded. Please ask your administrator to increase the quota limit or delete objects to reduce the used quota.]

For the registration of applications I'm using the free AAD license, which I understand has limits in the creation of applications; Currently the number is at 155.
I have already deleted the recycle bin but the error remains.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Hernán.

Comment: After you deleted the pipelines do they still show up under the "deleted pipelines"?  There's a difference in a "soft delete" vs a "hard delete", depending on your organization permissions.  A soft delete will require 30 days to pass before the pipeline is permanently gone.

Comment: Hi @Narthring. What I usually remove from the recycle bin are applications, not pipelines which are rarely deleted.